# How to safely pass variable to ADO.NET query without using parameter

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, openquery

The problem is this - I'm usign `SQL Server 2012` and I have 3 Linked IBM `DB2` servers so I need to use  `OPENQUERY`. However whe I tried to use :

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", clientId);
```

I get error : `an error occurred while preparing the query..`

After some time of investigantion I figured out that if I use concrete value in my query instead of trying tu pass it with parameter everything was working fine, so I get to the conclusion that the problem is not in my query or more precisely maybe it's in the query but because I'm trying to use `@param`. The after further investigation I got this: **`OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments.`** which I think seems to be the problem even though this is from year 2008 so the information is a little bit outdated.

However the best option would be to find a way to use parameters inside `OPENQUERY` but if that's really impossible in this scenarion what would be a save approach to pass the variable to my query?

Comment: I will just leave this here. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: How are you creating the query? What does it look like?

Comment: @SeanLange I think this is not very suitable for this question even though it's useful information by itself. As you can notice in this article, you still use parameter, just in some other way. And my first problem is using parameters at all. The way I use them, sure - is also important, but not the topic of this question.

Comment: @davidG It's pretty long to post the whole query here, there's nothing unusual in it. Is it you think that I should be able to use parameters inside `OPENQUERY` and the problem lies somewhere else? However if I'm right even `select * from openquery(LinkedServer, ' SELECT * FROM MyTable as tbl WHERE tbl.ID = @param') should not work.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, you cannot use parameters using [OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427(v=sql.110).aspx). Instead you could build up your SQL query and embed the values. So rather than this:

```
var sql = "select * from openquery(LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE tbl.ID = @param')";
```

You can do:

```
var someParameter = "SomeValue";
var rawQuery = "select * from openquery(LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE tbl.ID = ''{0}''')";
var sql = string.Format(rawQuery, someParameter);
```

However, you now need to be very careful of things like SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for the attention however things like SQL Injections were stoping me from doing something like `query.Replace("#id", clientId);` which I've been using when I need to pass data dynamically but it's safe.

Comment: It's not too hard to prevent injection. You tried with parameters but that is not available. Your only option is to do it this way but escape the input. It's pretty simple to do, lots of examples online.

Comment: Well, then instead of posting a code vlunarable to attacks why don't you just edit with some of the many examples online that you mentioned which is secure. And I'll be very thankfull as the other users that may visit this page and see some useful code isntead of `How NOT to do it` example.

Comment: The question was asking about a way to get a value into OPENQUERY, not prevent SQL injection. I just mentioned that as an exercise for the user.

Comment: I don't know what part of my post made you write this last comment. Is my title - `How to safely pass variable to ADO.NET query without using parameter` or my concluding question at the end - `what would be a save approach to pass the variable to my query?` made you think that giving answer which allows SQL injections is acceptable?